# Installing python packages offline

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python virtual environment created using virtualenv. 
Now I want to install different python packages like pandas or numpy. But is there any way to install these packages offline. Given, I already have these packages in base environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go and download packages from [pypi](https://pypi.org/). After that transport packages to your offline pc. open cmd and use this command. "pip install [Your packages path]".